# Can I apply different <LI> styles using classes

Tags: html

I have a single HTML document with multiple lists. It does not use any javascript, and I don't want it to. What I would like to do is somehow have some of those lists contain space between list elements and some lists have none.

I have created all of them with space at the moment by applying a style at the beginning of the document:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    li { margin-bottom: 1rem; }
  </style>
</head>
...
```

I would like to somehow apply this to only some of the lists.

I thought of applying a class to those lists, but am not sure how to format the class definition so that it affects **<li>** elements. I tried:

```
<style>
  li.spaced { margin-bottom: 1rem; }
</style>
```

and then using **<ol class="spaced">** and **<span style="spaced">** on the lists where I wanted the spacing, but that had no effect.

Is there a way to do that? Or some other way to achieve the effect without applying a style to each list element and without javascript? I looked at custom tags briefly, but it seems to involve javascript.

=== EDIT

I've had the following suggested answer, as I understand it, but when I display it in Chrome, there is no space between the elements of the list. Is there something wrong with it's formatting or something?

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    ol.spaced li = { margin-bottom: 1rem; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<ol class="spaced">
<li>one
<li>two
<li>three
</ol>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't know why I stuck an "=" in the style definition, but it breaks it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like:

**html**

```
<ol class="spaced>>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ol>
```

**css:**

```
ol.spaced li { margin-bottom: 1rem; }
```

---

`li.spaced { margin-bottom: 1rem; }` 
would require you to put spaced on every listitem:

```
<li class="spaced">Item</item>
<li class="spaced">Item</item>
```

**UPDATE:**
Everything between in `{ }` would be applied to the actual element selected:

Bottom:1rem and red text color for alla listitems within the ol that has class spaced:

```
ol.spaced li { 
    margin-bottom: 1rem; 
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I've tried what you asked, as I understand it, but it doesn't seem to be working. I've edited the question so I could show what I've tried -- is there something about it I've missed? It is self-contained there.

Comment: Ok, my bad -- I had stuck an "=" character in the style definition for some reason; once I take it out, this works.

Comment: Do you happen to know what the overall syntax for the class definition is? For instance, if I also wanted spaced lists to have an overall color (i.e., if I wanted to set a characteristic for these lists overall, in addition to setting one for the list items), what would lthat look definition look like?

Comment: I'm not sure I answered your question but take a look at my update.

Comment: Well, wanted to know what the formal syntax was, so that I could figure out how to apply a style to the "ol" in the same definition as the "li", or maybe apply one to "li" and one to some other tag -- I'm assuming there is some definition of correct syntax, either that there cannot be style applied to more than one kind of tag or a definition of how to do so. I wanted to open a chat window, but have to go somewhere right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add spacing like this

**HTML**

```
<ol class="list-space">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>

<span class="spaced">Some Other Text</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.list-spaced > li , spaced{
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

**This will add margin to all li items and other elements you want**